# Angularjs get image and pass into PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

I am new to angularjs domain so i can't understand how to do Image upload concept,

In registration form,am having option to upload image and enter personal details.

I understood how to pass details to php file using angular-js ,i did it below
like

```
    var app = angular.module('angularPostPHP', []);
app.controller('regCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.login = function () {
var request = $http({
    method: 'post',
    url:'http://localhost/HAP_testing/Registration.php',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'},
    data: {
        email: $scope.UserName,
        pass: $scope.FirstName
    }
});
/* Check whether the HTTP Request is successful or not. */
request.success(function (data) {
    alert("done"+data);
});

request.error(function(status)
{
 alert("Error"+status);
});
} });
```

but how we can pass user selected images into service,ng-model option will work only for input fileds

help me to resolve this issue ,Thanks advance.
if u having any reference link and sample please share me.

Comment: You didn't even describe your problem :\

Comment: Please do a search for `angular upload`

Comment: hi charlietfl ,i want pass image into php file using angular,is there any relevant sample

Comment: _ng-model option will work only for input fileds_ you sayed...
`<input type="file" name="uploaded_files" size="40">` it's an input field...
and use: `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on the form...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the base 64 format to upload your images.

Link : https://github.com/adonespitogo/angular-base64-upload

It converts your files from file format to base64 encoded models. You just need to specify this directive in your input tag .

```
<input type="file" ng-model="myfile" base-sixty-four-input>
```